# unable to see the desktop after installing 12.04 32bit in virtual box just logging into cmd interface

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, vmware

i am using win7 ultimate 64bit 
 my processor is amdfx6100
 motherboard is asusm5a78l-m/usb3

so can u suggest which version of ubuntu will work for me and in which software such as vmware ,virtual box

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite is virtual-box but that is just a mater of taste. Any one will do.

Are you sure you installed a desktop version? As far as I know only the server version comes with graphical interface disabled by default.

Login and type "startx" to start the window manager manually.